# How to bound $\sum e^{-a n^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $0<p<1$ and $a>0$. Then it would seem that
$$
\sum_1^\infty e^{-an^p}\le Ce^{-a}
$$
For some constant $C(p)$ since the terms in the summation decay exponentially. However, I can't quite figure out how would one approach this rigorously.

**EDIT**. Responding to @Brian Moehring comments, the idea is that I only care about large $a$ and fixed $p$. Now it's possible that $C(a,p)\sim C(p)/a^q$ so it diverges when $a\to0^+$, but since I only care about large $a$, the exponential term is what really dominates.

Comment: If you let either $p \to 0^+$ or $a \to 0^+$, the series diverges (essentially by the monotone convergence theorem), but if you let $C$ depend on both $a,p$, then really all you're saying is that the series converges.  What is the context for this question?

Comment: If I now understand your intent correctly, you're asking about this claim: "Fix $0 < p < 1$ and $\delta > 0$.  Then there is some constant $C = C(p,\delta)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-an^p} \leq Ce^{-a}$ for all $a \geq \delta$."  Is that an appropriate interpretation?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, that's what would be the exact statement. I provided an answer, though in my case $\delta$ depends on $p$, which is sufficient for my purpose, but probably could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution. Indeed, if the terms were something like
$$
\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1-q}}e^{-an^q}\le\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1-q}}e^{-ax^q}dx\le\frac{1}{qa}e^{-a}, \quad 0<q<1
$$
Now the polynomial term in the summation should not really affect anything for sufficiently large $n$ since the exponential term dominates. Hence, if for every $p$, we can find $q$ such that
$$
e^{-an^p} \le\frac{1}{n^{1-q}}e^{-an^q}
$$
Then the statement follows.

A possible choice would be such that if $pa>1$, then just choose $q<p$ and the assumption is satisfied. This choice could probably be improved, but this is sufficient for my purposes. Feel free to improve the estimate.